# Fixed topbar vs named anchors

Tags: css, positioning

I have a topbar with `position:fixed` which also contains anchor links (`<a href="#someid">jdjd</a>`).

The problem is that the target is placed in the top of the viewport (behind the fixed topbar).

how can I fix so the the browser scrolls so that the target is shown just below the topbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're being downvoted, it seems like an honest a good question.

I'd put a `margin-top` on the viewport, equal to the height of the fixed topbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/KfMLJ/ as an example

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "viewport", but giving `body` or `html` a `margin-top` will not affect where the browser scrolls. What I think the OP needs to do is either give the elements you can scroll to a `margin-top` _or_ add some click events to the links that override the default scroll and instead scrolls to the position of the target element - top bar height.

Comment: Example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/KfMLJ/  Class "container" is the viewport.

Comment: Hmm unsure what that's supposed to prove? (links don't even point to anything so impossible to test). But, if by viewport you mean the element being scrolled to then we're on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know there is no clean soloution. If you use inline scrollbar it can be achieved, but it needs a fixed height then.

2 soloutions found using CSS: http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Else you could pretty easy use JQUERY to measure the users height, put it into a container div, and have scrolling on that.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jpGdu/

Another soloution could be giving the element ur linking to a padding top (if it's h1 or whatever) :)