# :before pseudo element acting separately from parent element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a very similar question to this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005805/fixed-topbar-vs-named-anchors/10006010#10006010), but wasn't able to solve my problem.

I also referred to [Chris Coyier's tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/) and used his :before pseudo-element approach. However I cannot get the top of the `<section>` element to reflect the same top as it's `:before` child.

Here is some sample code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="about">
```

**CSS**

```
#about:before { 
display: block; 
content: " "; 
margin-top: -180px; 
height: 180px; 
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Here is [the website](http://ultradia.co/) I am working on so you can check it out live.

The reason I am wanting to do this is because my nav bar is fixed and whenever clicking on hash tag links from the nave bar it nearly cuts off the section title. I would just like to offset the stopping point of the scroll to add just a bit more padding between the title and nav bar.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How about more padding on the top of #about instead?

Comment: @BoltClock The only issue with this is it affects the layout of the page. Honestly I wouldn't mind doing this in my case but I want to be able to fix this if I encounter it in the future and so that other people can have the answer too! Thanks for the response!

Comment: Ah, fair enough! No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the `padding-top` on your section element is what is causing the problem. If you remove the padding it will work, however, all your spacing would need to be fixed.

I think the easiest thing for you to do would be to offset your scroll function... In agency.js add `- 70` after `scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top` on line 12:

```
// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top -70
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like you are correct on both accounts! Thanks for that. Wouldn't have guessed that padding effected that. I could have sworn I attempted offsetting that scroll function! Oh, well works for me! Thanks again.